# How to Implement Generic Enums and Traits in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, enums

I'm working on a Rust project where I have a set of algorithms (ALG1, ALG2, ALG3), and I want to implement them using traits and generics. I've defined an enum Algorithm to represent these algorithms, and corresponding traits ALG1Implementation, ALG2Implementation, and ALG3Implementation to define the behavior for each algorithm.

Here's what I have so far:

```
enum Algorithm {
    ALG1,
    ALG2,
    ALG3
}


pub trait ALG1Implementation {
    fn test(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) -> i32;
}

pub trait ALG2Implementation {
    fn test(b: u8, d: u8) -> u8;
}


pub trait ALG3Implementation {
    fn test(e: i16);
}


struct ExampleALGImpl_1;

impl ALG1Implementation for ExampleALGImpl_1 {
    fn test(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) -> i32 {
        a+b+c
    }
}


struct ExampleALGImpl_2;


impl ALG2Implementation for ExampleALGImpl_2 {
    fn test(b: u8, d: u8) -> u8{
        b*d
    }
}


struct ExampleALGImpl_3;

impl ALG3Implementation for ExampleALGImpl_3 {
    fn test(e: i16) {
        println!("{}", e);
    }
}



fn compute(alg: Algorithm) {
    todo()
}



struct OtherImplemetationForALG1;

impl ALG1Implementation for OtherImplemetationForALG1 {
    fn test(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) -> i32 {
        a*b*c
    }
}



fn main() {

    let result = compute(Algorithm::<ExampleALGImpl_1>::ALG1);
    let result2 =  compute(Algorithm::<OtherImplemetationForALG1>::ALG1);
    let result3 = compute(Algorithm::<ExampleALGImpl_2>::ALG2);
    let result4 =  compute(Algorithm::<ExampleALGImpl_3>::ALG3);

}
```

My goal is to make compute function generic so that it accepts different algorithm implementations based on the Algorithm enum.

**Specifically, I want to be able to do something like this:**

```
    let result = compute(Algorithm::<ExampleALGImpl_1>::ALG1);
    let result2 =  compute(Algorithm::<OtherImplemetationForALG1>::ALG1);
    let result3 = compute(Algorithm::<ExampleALGImpl_2>::ALG2);
    let result4 =  compute(Algorithm::<ExampleALGImpl_3>::ALG3);
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to achieve this. How can I implement these generics properly to make my code work as intended? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:** I've edited the code, i hope it is more clear what i'm trying to achieve. ALG1, ALG2, and ALG3 have different templates and could be implemented in different ways

**EDIT2:** [Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX0Zt.jpg)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this abstraction? Why not make each algorithm a function and call the functions directly from `main()`? If the algorithms are somehow "interchangeable", i.e. they take the same type of input and produce the same type of output, then they would all need to implement the same trait, instead of three different traits.

Comment: Each algorithm will have more then one function, for simplicity I have only listed one for each. Every function will take different type of inputs

Comment: Agree with @Thomas it isn't clear why you need any of this, at all. What it *looks* like you are trying to do is simulate function overloading for your compute function, which is arguably a bad idea and usually indicates an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please post a less abstract answer of what you're trying to achieve here, and please make sure it includes your *actual* goals rather than something like "simulate function overloading in Rust".

Comment: @JaredSmith I've updated my question, i hope it is more clear now

Comment: @Alberto eh, not really? As I understand it you want a `compute` function, that can take one of several algorithms, that can have multiple implementations? To give a concrete example a function that can do either graph search for a node or path traversal depending on the enum, and if given the path variant would be generic over the implementation (e.g. Dijkstra vs A*)? I'm still trying to wrap my brain around why you need all these different things in **one** `compute` function. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Also per my earlier comment, people are (still) not getting it from your toy example. Post something *real*, because in these examples it still isn't clear why anyone would ever try to do what you are doing. This still reads like you're trying to [greenspun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule) patterns from another language into Rust and I'm still strongly suspecting there's a more idiomatic solution for what you *actually* want.

Comment: @JaredSmith i've uploaded a picture which describes what i'm trying to do

Comment: @Alberto Why do you need a single algorithm trait that the algorithms implement. It looks like you are missing some sort of 'task' unit that would be composed from the specific task, inputs and output locations for the algorithm.